# Auto-import vue components in seperate template scripts

Tags: vuejs3, vite, element-plus, auto-import

I am trying to use a dynamic HTML template for my component. Auto import doesn't work when template is imported, but works when otherwise.

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { ElementPlusResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver({
        importStyle: "sass",
      })],
    }),
  ]
})
```

The above (vite config) worked well for SFC without dynamic templates.